# Central vertical align within flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a flexbox layout as illustrated below:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:stretch;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  background-color:grey;
}
header {
  background-color:green;
  height:3em;
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
main {
  display:flex;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:yellow;
}
nav {
  flex:0 0 100px;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:grey;
}
#wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:red;
}
#content {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:white;
}
footer {
      height: 1em;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
     0<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</main>
```

The scroll works as expected and I see from 0 to 29.

But if I have a single line of 29, how can I make this single line centrally aligned within the content?

I tried to set `display:flex` and `align-items:center` on `content`, that works for single line, but makes the top of the content disappear in case of long content.

Desired result for one line:
[image: Result for single line]

Comment: can you attach the image what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It might be because of the <br>. They're also getting centered and that's what might mess up the layout. Try separating them somehow else

Comment: I have the same issue when the content is a form

Comment: @Carlo use `span` instead of `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Because of `<br>,` you can't align the items. you can try like this using `span`
To the horizontal

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 3em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

nav {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
}

footer {
  height: 1em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>6</span>
      <span>7</span>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>9</span>
      <span>10</span>
      <span>11</span>
      <span>12</span>
      <span>13</span>
      <span>14</span>
      <span>15</span>
      <span>16</span>
      <span>17</span>
      <span>18</span>
      <span>19</span>
      <span>20</span>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</main>
```

For vertical try this hope this will help you.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 3em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

nav {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
}

footer {
  height: 1em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>6</span>
      <span>7</span>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>9</span>
      <span>10</span>
      <span>11</span>
      <span>12</span>
      <span>13</span>
      <span>14</span>
      <span>15</span>
      <span>16</span>
      <span>17</span>
      <span>18</span>
      <span>19</span>
      <span>20</span>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</main>
```

If you want vertically center align then add this `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your image. I think this is what you're looking for. `<br>` won't work for you as you need to provide `height` to each element so I've replaced it with `div` that may contain some `forms` or any other data.

```css
 html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:stretch;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  background-color:grey;
}
header {
  background-color:green;
  height:3em;
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
main {
  display:flex;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:yellow;
}
nav {
  flex:0 0 100px;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:grey;
}
#wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:red;
}
#content {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:white;
}
#content > div{ border:1px solid #ccc; height:100vh; display:flex; align-items: center;  }
footer {
      height: 1em;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
     <div>0</div>
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
     <div>4</div>
     <div>5</div>
     <div>6</div>
     <div>7</div>
     <div>8</div>
     <div>9</div>
     <div>10</div>
     <div>11</div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me since the content of `content` will be variable. In case there is only `<div>0</div>`, it is vertically centered but there is a scroll bar for no reason

Comment: @Carlo That's because of height given as 100vh to div inside #content. You can reduce it as required or until scrollbar disappears. 80vh worked for me while trying.